# Ignore empty tiles in gdal2tiles.py when generating tiles

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles

I am in the process of generating a large set of tiles from a .vrt file composed of many images. The image is following a road section, being very long and small strip of images and  due the shape of the road the bounding box around it contains a ratio of 80% no data and 20% beign the actually road. This means gdal2tiles takes forever since its looping over all tiles in the boundingbox and not just the area that has data.

Is there any way to tell gdal2tiles to skip those tiles?

Alternative I have split the vtr file into lesser areas but then in the intersection of the two tiles sets that I need to combine after the two sets has tiles defined for the same area with half filled map and nodata and taking either of them causes the map to have big black stripes down in between.

Any suggestions to make this go more smooth?

Comment: did you ever find an answer? I am making many empty tiles at the moment

Comment: @JoostDöbken, check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379745/69112. It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

`gdal2tiles -x` option will exclude empty tiles.

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/8a1db0f952142f211367d922e4467e6d730c39d1/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py#L1449